# Unexpected alert while closing Firefox web-driver in python

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a simple script in python for logging into a web-site using selenium web-driver. The problem is when I'm trying to close web-driver, FireFox gives me an unexpected alert. This is my script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import *

class ClassTest(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get('url')


    def login(self, username, password): 
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("username").clear()
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("password").clear()
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()

    def logout():
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('logout').click()        

    def __del__(self):
        self.logout()
        self.driver.close()
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = ClassTest()
    test.login('myUsername', 'myPasswd')
```

I tried two ways for closing web-driver window; first by just using `self.driver.close()` and second by using `self.driver.quit()` after `self.driver.close()`. Both gives me the same result. The stack-trace is as following:

```
Message: u'Modal dialog present' ; Stacktrace: 
    at nsCommandProcessor.prototype.execute (file:///c:/users/user/appdata/local/temp/tmpeqmito/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10949)
    at Dispatcher.executeAs/< (file:///c:/users/user/appdata/local/temp/tmpeqmito/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:7717)
    at Resource.prototype.handle (file:///c:/users/user/appdata/local/temp/tmpeqmito/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:7864)
    at Dispatcher.prototype.dispatch (file:///c:/users/user/appdata/local/temp/tmpeqmito/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:7811)
    at WebDriverServer/<.handle (file:///c:/users/user/appdata/local/temp/tmpeqmito/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:10740)
    at <anonymous> (file:///c:/users/user/appdata/local/temp/tmpeqmito/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1935)
    at ServerHandler.prototype.handleResponse (file:///c:/users/user/appdata/local/temp/tmpeqmito/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:2261)
    at Connection.prototype.process (file:///c:/users/user/appdata/local/temp/tmpeqmito/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1168)
    at RequestReader.prototype._handleResponse (file:///c:/users/user/appdata/local/temp/tmpeqmito/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1616)
    at RequestReader.prototype._processBody (file:///c:/users/user/appdata/local/temp/tmpeqmito/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1464)
    at RequestReader.prototype.onInputStreamReady (file:///c:/users/user/appdata/local/temp/tmpeqmito/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js:1333)
```

This is the alert:

[image]

Any idea about the reason???

**EDIT 1:**

I've had some workaround and I found out that whenever I don't log-out from web-site, there is no alert. Maybe something's wrong with the log-out button or the process behind it. Its HTML code is this:

```
<img src="/images/button/exit.png" class="gwt-Image" name="logout" title="Log Off">
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that dialog is displayed when an AJAX call is interruped.  I generally see it in Chrome and Firefox.

A couple of suggestions.

Put a short sleep after the logout.  I believe there may be AJAX running around the logout, and using a short sleep may allow the AJAX to run to completion.

```
import time

self.logout()
time.sleep(5)
self.driver.close()
self.driver.quit()
```

Wrap an `alert.accept()` in a `try-except`:

```
self.logout()
try:
    alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
    alert.accept()
    print "alert accepted"
except TimeoutException:
    print "no alert"
self.driver.close()
self.driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already knew that concept @Richard, I want to know the exact reason for this behavior.